# Order IEnumerable<T> object based on Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, dictionary

I have a `IEnumerable<T>` list. - T is a custom type, one of the members of that type is an int called Id.

I also have a `Dictionary<int, int>`object the first int is an Id (this id will be in the `IEnumerable<T>` list. The second Int is a rating number.

I want to order the `IEnumerable<T>` list based on the rating inside `Dictionary<int, int>` - Highest First

I can do this by if statements and looping, but I have a feeling this can be done using a linq/lambda statement.

Any one got any ideas how this can be done?

I'm guessing something like  `list.OrderBy(x => x.id == Dictionaryname.  something something something`

Comment: If you want to know how to get the value for a key from a dictionary then look at the documentation of `Dictionary`, it has many examples of how to go about doing that.

Comment: You can use a custom comparer on the `OrderBy` method that keys into the dictionary and checks whether item `a` should come before, at the same position or after item `b`, or if your dictionary is keyed by the id property, you can just access the dictionary directly in the `OrderBy` lamba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use the [OrderByDescending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534855(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var sorted = list.OrderByDescending(x => dictionary[x.id])
```

Comment: Im going to try this out now... but can you explain it a little better how does it know to order it based on the rating number in the dictionary (the second Int) I ask this because the first int in the dictionary is the id, I want to sort it by the rating number

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
list.OrderByDescending(x => dictionary[x.id])
```